# Spring RestController gives 404 Error with Netbeans and TomCat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to start my first Springboot application with Netbeans 13 and Apache Tomcat 8.5.81. I created a WebApplication project and edited the POM by adding:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
</dependencies> 
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
```

Then I created the following rest controller:

```
package com.springboot.springtemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class WebController
{
  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public String home()
   {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return "<h1> Hi!</h1>"  ;
  }      
}
```

and the main file:

```
package com.springboot.springtemplate;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Accessing http://localhost:8080/SpringTemplate/index.html gives the desired result, instead
http://localhost:8080/SpringTemplate/hello gives 404 error. It seems releated with the context path, but I cannot get rid of the problem. The web.xml file, which was autogenerated by Netbeans, is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

while dispatcher-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

 </beans>
```

Notice also that the latter xml file was autogenerated.

Comment: Dont think you need 'SpringTemplate' in the url, just try this and see if you are able to access the endpoint
http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: This is the so-called "context". The problem is the compatibility between Tomcat and the Spring Framework versions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related with the versions of Tomcat and Spring. Switching to Tomcat 10.x and Spring 3.x resolved.